# Apple Push Notifications won't arrive when screen is unlocked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, apple-push-notifications

I've been trying to find something about this problem for a few days, but without any useful results. I'm working on a VoIP app for iOS (using an iPhone 4 running iOS 6.0) in Objective-c which uses remote notifications to notify the user about calls when the client is in background.
My issue is quite strange: When the app is in background and the screen is locked, notifications arrive and work perfectly - they ring, and open the app when opened. But when the application is in background, and the screen is unlocked - for example, we're on the home screen - notifications simply fail to appear, not giving any sign that something happened.

Anybody got any ideas where to look around? The app code handles push notifications correctly when they appear, so that shouldn't be an issue. The notifications get out of our server, so I'm starting to think that there is something about the device's settings. The app is set to a "banner" alert style, and its notifications are enabled.

Comment: You may wanna look into your device's settings. Check if notification alert type is set to none

Comment: It's set to "Banners", Notification Center is turned on, along with Badge App Icon, Sounds and View in Lock Screen.

Comment: Since you do not receive any alert, check whether the notification goes to Notification Center. Does it reaches there?

Comment: Nope, Notification Center shows any sign of notifications if the screen was locked while they arrived. Another interesting addition is that if the app is _not_ running when the remote notification arrives, it shows correcly again - the issue arises only when the app is running, but is in the background.

Answer (score 3):

When the app is running in the background, the notification does not appear. You need to catch it in the App Delegate `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`. 
Implement this method and put a UIAlert to see when the notification arrives.